# reopen hidden form at new location

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am working on a map, google map for example. and the map is draggable, ofcourse.

this is the whole code on `onMarker_Click` ..

```
For Each m In mList
            If item.ToolTipText = m Then
                Dim f As New Form2
                Me.AddOwnedForm(f)
                With f
                    .Show()
                    Dim p As New Point
                    p = item.LocalPosition + New Point(20, -240)
                    .Location = p
                    .Text = m
                End With
                Exit Sub
            End If

        Next
```

basically, this code generates a new form beside the point every time I click the marker.. gives me the result that I want, however, I can't use this code on `onMapDrag` event. Why? for every pixel dragged, it creates a new instance.

My goal is to be able to drag the map, with form following the marker. but it seems impossible for me now. so what I am thinking today is..
I have 3 open forms displaying something and when I *drag* the map, form *hides* and after dragging, form *reappears* still beside the **new positioned** marker.
flow should be something like this :

```
onMarker_Click()
'Code on top

onMapDrag()
'hide visible forms / close them

onMouse_Leave()
'show hidden forms / reopen them but I need the same forms which were closed
'show hidden forms beside the marker

'since I cannot literally *drag* form2
'I am thinking of hiding it, and show it on the next destination after drag
```

please don't hesitate to ask if there is something you don't understand. I need this now. thanks SO people.

Comment: If the `dim f as new Form2` is in the Drag event it makes sense that new forms open for every pixel, since the drag event would fire constantly (like MouseMove). Try adding every form that you create in MarkerClicked to a List(Of Form). Then, in onMapDrag you scrap the whole New Form code and instead iterate through every form in the list and change their positions/Hide the forms. And in onMouseUp event (or similar) you call .Show for every form in the list again.

Comment: that's an idea! give me time, needed to plot this first :) ty